# Google Analytics for website with internet and intranet URL?

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, universal-analytics

I want to monitor the traffic for one of the websites hosted in our organization.This website is available over internet and intranet.

Internet URL :

```
https://'portal'.xyz.com  (xyz.com is domain name)
```

Intranet URL :

```
https://'portal'(This is without FQDN and can be reached without having internet connection)
```

I have 2 questions below:
1.How do I configure google analytics to work with nonFQDN (Intranet) version of the website too? Some of the posts mentioning doing below changes to the tracking code once its generated.This is for universal analytics.
    `ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'none');`

2.If I do changes mentioned in 1 to tracking code ,will I be able to monitor traffic on both URLs (Intranet and internet) using single profile on google analytics?

Any pointers would be much appreciated? Thanks.